# How can I do redirects using middleware with next-auth

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I want to redirect the user when the path is / to /trade but I have tried as a middleware would normally do but next-auth stops working.

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    if (req.nextUrl.pathname === "/") {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/trade', req.url))
    }
}

export const config = { matcher: ["/", "/trade"] };
```